# Expires Headers Shows New Time Every Refresh

Tags: caching, http-headers, nginx, browser-cache

Please see [HERE](http://217.23.9.121/wp-content/themes/af-red/images/media_cloud.png)

Everytime I refresh the page, the Expires headers changes to *Current Time + 1 year"

Is it cacheing or not ?

My nginx config has the following cache settings:

```
location ~
\.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pp$
{
    expires 31536000s;
    add_header Pragma "public";
    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
}
```

Comment: looks like it's caching to me.

Comment: I get the feeling that it is "re-cacheing" on every page load. Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the Output of response header

```
 Expires:Sun, 10 Feb 2013 04:14:33 GMT
```

And status code is

```
 Status Code:304 Not Modified
```

This image is cached.

Comment: Its giving 200 in safari and 304 in crome and firefox.

Comment: It seems that safari is dropping If-Modified-Since in request headers you can refer this article http://use.perl.org/~bart/journal/36598.  changing something   in this config may help but I am not sure what to change.

Comment: Hmm I am using Chrome (on mac) but I get issue on safari too